# ¿Cómo incluyo un Java Bean dentro de una posición de una lista con JSTL?

Tags: spring, jstl

Intento agregar un Java bean dentro de una lista con JSTL imitando asi el comportamiento de un contador, pero no se como agregarlo o si es posible.

Java Bean creado con JSTL:

```
<c:set var="cont" value="${0}" />
```

Lista donde lo quiero incluir y que se incremente de uno en uno el objeto previamente creado:

```
 <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${videosControl[cont].status eq 1}">
           <input type="checkbox" checked>
           <c:set var="cont" value="${cont+1}" />
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
          <input type="checkbox">
          <c:set var="cont" value="${cont+1}" />
        </c:otherwise>
  </c:choose>
```

Intente tambien esto:

Cree una variable contador y lo agregue al modelo con Spring:

```
int cont = 0;
        
model.addAttribute("cont", cont);
```

Luego en el archivo jsp realicé el mismo codigo pero no supe como interactuar con el objeto de modelo para asi poder modificarlo e incrementar de uno en uno la posición de la lista.

Cualquier posible solución o alternativa es bienvenida, gracias.